# Debugging Java JNI from core dump of unhandled CXX exception

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, native, portable-executable

Given a JNI core dump message, such as the following, how does one go about debugging the native frames?

I'd tried opening the DLL in a disassembler, however, I didn't find anything relevant at the specified offsets. Basically I'm looking at Java_Planning14_0.dll at offset 0x288dd in IDA Pro, but there's no function at that address. Is there something I'm missing about the interpretation of the offsets in this message?

```
Stack: [0x14f20000,0x15120000],  sp=0x1511f5a4,  free space=2045k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0xc42d]
C  [MSVCR90.dll+0x5df60]
C  [Java_Planning14_0.dll+0x288dd]
C  [Java_Planning14_0.dll+0x2a1fd]
[Snip various java frames]
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x153efa]
V  [jvm.dll+0x22311e]
```

How does one go about debugging this type of error? I have the source for the library, but that sort of defeats the purpose of what I'm asking. Is there any conveneient way to find out what proceudre was executing at the time? Ideally with the source file and line number?

Comment: Some IDE's allow you to load the core dump in debug mode, and you can see exactly where it broke and the stack trace. Under ubuntu, I use Qt creater IDE for that, specifically for that JNI debugging

Comment: @GigaStore interesting. Does that include the native frames, so I could see where the native code broke?

Comment: you mean the native code? the c/c++ code? If so, yes. Its the source code I load on qt creater (a C/C++ IDE) before loading the core dump.